# Configuring TCP for a very high volume network

Tags: networking, tcp, crash, buffer-overflow

Currently experiencing a network issue in a system consisting of 2 sensors (each with a data rate of 1Khz), communicating with a Windows 7 operating system via ethernet link. The program running on the windows system is written in Java.

The issue: Program runs as normal for a undefined period of time, before coming to a halt – due to a TCP native buffer overflow.

My instincts leads me to believe this is due to the TCP RWIN – in that the consumer is too slow in comsuming packets from the stack, eventually leading to a buffer overflow.

Looking at the captured packets from the NIC, the final sequences before the crash always look like this: a large ACK block, followed by a RST from each sensor, before shutting down the connection. We can see on each RST the WIM size is set to 200, whereas before it was upwards of 1000.

[image]

Could anyone offer some suggestions on how to begin solving this issue? In all the research  done at this point, I’m still at a loss as to how to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensor is sending a RST, then the connection got closed at the sensor. You should investigate why that happened? One reason might be that the connection got timed out -- perhaps TCP@sensors were trying to send something and could not get through. Can you run some trace tool (like tcpdump/windump) at sensors?